# Video encoding quality, azure media services

Tags: encoding, azure-media-services, videoquality

The video quality of the first few seconds of encoded videos using azure do not look very good.  It is lower quality and blurry.  The quality improves afterwards dramatically.
What settings do you recommend to make sure the first frames are excellent quality.  First perception is very important.
Thanks,
Osama

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible that you observe this kind of behavior if you have encoded your file for adaptive streaming. In this case, the output asset is composed by different files of different quality (poor and high quality).

When you play an adaptive stream, the first parts downloaded are from the poor quality files and then the player detects your bandwidth and adapt the stream to a higher quality, automatically. If you look at YouTube, Netflix or Dailymotion, you will observe the exact same behavior. It allows to adapt the stream to the available bandwidth.

If you do not want an adaptive stream, you need to use a preset that encode the file in a given bitrate / quality.

The list of supported presets is here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt269960.aspx

Multiple bitrates presets are for adaptive streaming.
Single bitrate presets are for single bitrate file.

For example, if your original video is 1080p, you can use this preset: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt269926.aspx

But be careful that all your users that will have a low bandwidth may not be able to play your content in a smooth way.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Julien, 
You are probably seeing the Adaptive Bitrate streaming ramp up when playing back the content.  That's normal behavior for adaptive streaming.

You can eliminate some of the lower bitrates from the encoding preset or restrict them at the client side using the Azure Media Player SDK.

Keep in mind that you can always customize your encoding presets. We support JSON schema for preset and you can define your own based on our existing presets that we ship as a "best practice" to get folks started.

I would recommend using the Azure Media Explorer tool to play around with different encoding settings and easily launch the player for preview.  Go here to access the tool from our download page:
http://aka.ms/amse